# Как установить getsureImage?

Tags: android-sdk, android

[gesture-imageview](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview)

Помогите установить `getsureImage`. Просто в android нет готового элемента с Zoom функцией. Вот в недрах интернета нашел это. Но при установке он ругается на R.com. что-то там. Вообще помогите установить её, вы же профи, использую среду IDEA. Дайте инструкцию для новичка, как это сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Взял отсюда: [How pinch zoom image in image zoom android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894215/how-pinch-zoom-image-in-image-zoom-android)

Comment: Можно хотя бы написать норм**е**льно? А то все дай то, дай сё... Элементарное уважение должно же быть: правильно сформулировать вопрос и написать без ошибок, а то мы не понимаем что такое `getsureImage` и 
>R.com.что то там...вообще помогите установить её

Comment: Вот же написал: "Дайте инструкцию для новичка как это сделать, буду очень благодарен". Насчет getsureImage, вверху же ссылка есть, за что МИНУС то поставили? Я же написал, что требуется помощь от профи.

Comment: не `getsureImage`,а `gestureImage` - будьте внимательнее!

Comment: @xTIGRx, а все потому, что в zip архиве находится модуль библиотеки, который нужно извлечь и подключить к проекту.

Comment: @xTIGRx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) - поддерживает основные жесты, есть возможность более тонкой настройки. 
Для подключения в файле build.gradle своего модуля пропишите в раздел dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
}
```

Как работает:

```
ImageView mImageView;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

    // Set the Drawable displayed
    Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

    // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
}

// If you later call mImageView.setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap/setImageResource/etc then you just need to call
attacher.update();
```

Comment: PhotoView, поддерживает, увеличение и уменьшение 2 пальцами?, потому что gesture-imageview, все поддерживает, только я не умею устанавливать их, могу jar библиотеку подключить, а zip не знаю как

Comment: @xTIGRx, да, поддерживает. И по 2-му тапу тоже поддерживает. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.photoview.sample пример работы. Я написал выше, как подключить к вашему проекту.

Comment: А как использовать без градие? Что нужно вытащить из архива?

Comment: Дай инструкцию, плиз, как установить PhotoView в IDEA, плиз.

Comment: @xTIGRx, если у вас Android Studio, то там сборка делается через gradle. Так что это самый быстрый вариант.

Comment: Нет, я использую IDEA без градие.

Comment: @xTIGRx, думаю, все-же используете. Читается как "Градл". Вот ссылка на jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/library/1.2.2/library-1.2.2.jar